Converting planar local coordinates to ellipsoid coordinates
I am new to GIS and QGIS.
I am trying to create a display layer of survey points on a factory floor (planar) so that they represent correctly when overlaid. I want the points to appear overlaid on a floorplan of the factory (which was georeferenced using EPSG:3857 and overlaid on a OSM map layer using EPSG:3857 CRS).
The factory floorplan overlays properly on the OSM map.
I have tried adding the x,y delta (in meters) of the survey point to the EPSG:3857 coordinate at the origin using a spreadsheet and saved in CSV. When the CSV is used to generate a layer the overlay is displayed but the points (other than 0,0) do not appear where they should on the underlying floorplan.
I'm assuming this is because the point delta is a planar measurement and the floorplan coordinates are ellipsoid.
Is there a plugin or python script to make this conversion or am I missing something more obvious?

Where on the world does your 0,0 point appear?

You absolutely do not want to do factory floorplans in Web Mercator (where distance units are completely meaningless) -- all measurements would be suspect.

Thanks Vince, is there planar projection I can use to georeference my floorplan and would that allow me to add/subtract my survey points with an accurate overlay depiction?

You could literally use any projection (but a Mercator) for this. The key here is that your survey points aren't tied to the globe, so while you could use any projection, you couldn't provide them to anyone else for any purpose where they might assume that the coordinate reference is real (nor could you use them that way yourself).

It worked! Thanks Vince!!
